# Logging into a profile take more than 45 seconds in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, user-profile

My Ubuntu 12.04 installation has /home on a separate partition. After I installed Ubuntu 12.04, the logging in time to my profile has increased tremendously - a min of 45 secs to get the desktop.

I tried removing some startup programs like checking for hardware drivers, empathy, orca screen reader and screensaver, but it did not help.

Has anyone got any suggestion?

Comment: Preload may help you
sudo apt-get install preload ,

try unity --reset for removing extra compiz effects

Answer (score 0):

it may be acceptable if you have an old machine years back, but I guess it's not the point of this topic :,) so let's try to press F7 while booting to track what's happening or any stuff slows down the launching speed.

Comment: Its an i5 processor laptop! And the issue is after I reach the login screen. Does F7 work at login screen?

Comment: F7 may only work while booting process, you mean it takes 45 secs to the desktop after entering password? if so, please try to check logs, such as syslog, dmesg located at /etc/logs, hope it helps.

Comment: @ vicd: Thanks. I found nothing suspicious. Just cant figure out what to do!

Comment: from the information you provided so far, it may be difficult to investigate what's going wrong with your system. When the loggin prompt displays, immediately press `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, try to log in with the shell mode, is the login progress normal?

Comment: nothing much happens when i switch over to the tty . i can login almost instantly. i have done `unity --reset` to see if that helps.